# Android - Does Lollipop Screen pinning work across multiple activities in the same app?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

I'm attempting to add kiosk functionality to an android application. I'm hoping to take advantage of Lollipop's screen pinning feature to automatically pin the app once it starts. The app UI has been built with several different activities. I call `startLockTask()` once during the `onCreate()` method of the entry-point activity however as soon as I navigate to another activity within the app it unpins.

Do I need to call `startLockTask()` in every activity during `onCreate()/onResume()`? This will produce a poor user experience as the "Screen pinned" toast will appear every time I move from one activity to another within the app.

I'm developing the app on a Moto E (2nd gen) running Android 5.0.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Lollipop's Screen Pinning feature pins a Single Task NOT an Activity on the screen. So if your activities are in one single task then yes you can play/switch between activities in screen pinning mode.

For more details you can check this official information: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise > Screen pinning

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It looks like I needed to tweak the launch mode of some of my activities in the manifest. Thanks.